# Grep lines from the log with matching pattern using Unix command

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have logs in this format. I'm looking to get logs only that has count more than 5000.

Matching pattern should be Count [value greater than 5000]

```
INFO 56783 Count [5987] 
INFO 67988 Count [4986] 
INFO 27679 Count [9865]
```

In the above example, the output should be only

```
 INFO 56783 Count [5987]
```

I'm using in the following format

```
sudo cat <path to log> | grep 'Count [5[0-9][0-9][0-9]]'
```

Any ideas what is missing here

Comment: Just one correction. Output should contain `9865` also as it is `> 5000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```sh
grep -E 'Count \[[5-9][0-9]{3,}\]' file

INFO Count [5987]
INFO Count [9865]
```

Here regex pattern is `\[[5-9][0-9]{3,}\]` that matches a:

- `\[`: Match opening `[`
- `[5-9]`: Match digits between `5` to `9`
- `[0-9]{3,}`: Match 3 or more digits
- `\]`: Match closing `]`

This will match `5000` or an integer greater than `5000` inside `[...]`.

However, you should be using `awk` for this job to get most flexibility:

```sh
awk '$2 == "Count" && gsub(/[][]/, "", $3) && $3+0 > 5000' file

INFO Count 5987
INFO Count 9865
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, can you please help me in understanding \[[5-9][0-9]{3,}\]

Comment: I have added regex details in answer.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Cheers!

Comment: Quick question, if I want to pull values ONLY that are less than 5000?

Comment: Using `grep` that regex will be a bit more involved by using `awk` it be just `< 5000` in condition above.

Comment: Using `grep` for values `< 5000`, use `grep -E 'Count \[([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2}|[1-4][0-9]{3})\]' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
awk -F'[][]' '/Count \[[0-9]+]/ && $2 > 5000' file
```

The field separator matches `]` or `[` and `/Count \[[0-9]+]/ && $2 > 5000` only outputs lines that contain `Count [<number>]` and where Field 2 is more than 5K.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/0UJKe3):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='INFO Count [5987] 
INFO Count [4986] 
INFO Count [9865] '
awk -F'[][]' '/Count \[[0-9]+]/ && $2 > 5000' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
INFO Count [5987] 
INFO Count [9865]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it should match the exact string as "Count [5987]". Can we do it with grep?

Comment: @Syed I added the obligatory `Count [number]` part. With `grep`, you can use `grep '\[[5-9][0-9]\{3,\}]' file`.

Comment: @Syed Yes, and this works for that edit, too.

Comment: Quick question, if I want to pull values ONLY that are less than 5000? by using grep

Comment: @Syed ``grep -E 'Count \[[1-4]?[0-9]{1,3}]' file`` / ``grep 'Count \[[1-4]\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,3\}]' file``, see https://regex101.com/r/gVh7tp/1